# Adding a ternary operator to a hyperlink in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am working on adding an if statement to my while loop that is returned from my mysql query.
I have 4 document paths, depending on the category the path is different.
I have been searching Google all day, so far the best I  have been able to come up with is using a Ternary which i have put into my code but it keeps throwing an err, and I get a blank white page. I think I must have my quotes wrong or something.
I need to repeat the if statement 4 times but i am trying to get it to work right once first.

Here is my code.

```
    echo "<td><a href=\"".((.$row ['category'].=='Validation_Letter') ? "../../../../Docs/Doc/val_letters/":"")."".$row ['filepath']."\">".$row ['filepath']."</a></td>";
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: quarry. if you dive at night you can find them close to the coastline, don't you? Tip: Split your code over multiple lines. It's not that as of today we really need to save space on the harddisk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the two periods in  .$row['category'].=='Validation_Letter'

echo "".$row ['filepath']."";

It works like this - ( $val == true ? 'true' : 'false' )

Comment: Thank you very much that salved the problem.

Comment: the parenthesis are also optional.

Comment: No, actually. In his example they are required